# Select record by month between 12 and 2 of new Year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this record:

```
[id | dateofit ]
[ 1 | 2017-12-1]
```

Which I want to select using this Query:

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE MONTH(dateofit) BETWEEN 12 AND 2
```

The problem is that `12` is from year `2017` and `2` from year `2018`, So I don't get any results,

I tried to replace the Query like this `MONTH(dateofit) BETWEEN MONTH(12) AND MONTH(1)` But still the same problem

What I want to do is to select records has a month of [12, 1(newyear), 2(newyear)]

Comment: why not simply use `dateofit >= '2017-12-01' and dataofit < '2018-03-01'`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala You may post that as an answer.  It would also be sargable.

Comment: How do you determine it is year 2017 given a start and end number (12 & 2)?

Comment: @kc2018 that was the problem, So i'll provide the timestamp instead.

Comment: Can you assume the ending month is in the current year (2018)?

Comment: @kc2018 now i see another problem, thanks to you, I actually want to select all records having the months between the two numbers without caring about the year too.

Comment: Use `IN (12, 1, 2)` if you don't care about the year.

Comment: @kc2018 would using `MONTH(dateofit) IN (12 ,1 ,2)` harm the performance? I just read about the `sargable queries` thanks to ***Tim*** and made me think that there is also a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not provide just the time-range?

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE dateofit BETWEEN "2017-12-01 00:00:00" AND "2018-03-01 23:59:59";
```

Comment: What in case I wanted to select all records having the month between `12` and `2` without caring about the year?

Comment: Then you use `month(date of it) in (12,1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's two possible approaches:
If you only have data from March 2017 to November 2018:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    records
WHERE
    MONTH(dateofit) IN (12, 1, 2)
```

If you have mulitple years of data:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    records
WHERE
    dateofit BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2018-02-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM records 
WHERE ( YEAR(dateofit) = 2017 AND MONTH(dateofit) = 12) OR 
      ( YEAR(dateofit) = 2018 AND MONTH(dateofit) IN (1, 2));
```